# How to install CentOS 8 from disk withoud USB/DVD

Tags: linux, partitioning, bootloader, bootable-media

I have 2 hard disk and in disk number (2) I have a partition with size 10 GB. now I want to write the CentOS ISO image file to this partition and boot my system and install the OS into the disk number (1). is it possible? (of course It is!) how should I write this image so that I can boot from this partition?

my system is EFI (not legacy).

Comment: Are you using EFI boot or BIOS (legacy) boot?

Comment: @gronostaj  it is EFI

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using EFI boot, you can simply extract the ISO image to any FAT32 partition and boot it. EFI doesn't use any hidden data such as bootsectors, it's only relying on presence of some files in filesystem hierarchy.

On Linux the ISO can be mounted and its content copied to destination. On Windows I'm using 7-Zip for this purpose. Don't use Windows's ISO mounting feature - some ISOs are crafted to be read slightly differently by Windows and files extracted this way won't be bootable.

Unfortunately some ISOs aren't compatible with this trick, but there's no harm in trying.

Comment: thank you for your answer. right now I am using Linux `dd` command to copy the entire image to the partition, but the partition format is ext4 I guess. does this works or I abort it?

Comment: That's something completely different. You're overwriting the filesystem on the partition with the filesystem inside ISO. The filesystem on the ISO is ISO9660 and most likely won't be readable for UEFI. You need to extract ISO _contents_ to a FAT32 partition.

Comment: "you can simply extract the ISO image to any FAT32 partition and boot it" , really?!  I Love `EFI` !

Comment: I did what you said, does not work. I can boot from the partition but I get errors in the very first stages of installation process.

Comment: I'm afraid that's one of these incompatible ISOs. The ISO can make additional assumptions about installation media, in these cases this method won't work.

Comment: it is the official CentOS 8 image